# Why can't this macro handle trailing comma?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! vec {
    ( $( $x:expr ),* ) => {
        {
            let mut temp_vec = Vec::new();
            $(
                temp_vec.push($x);
            )*
            temp_vec
        }
    };
}
```

The book says "The comma following `$()` indicates that a literal comma separator character could **optionally** appear after the code that matches the code in `$()`. The `*` specifies that the pattern matches zero or more of **whatever precedes the** `*`."

I notice that this matches `vec![1,2,3,4]` but not `vec![1,2,3,4,]` which should match according to the interpretation above. The comma is certainly not optional in the middle and must not appear optionally at trailing position according to the compiler. But if `*` governs the whole '`$( $x:expr ),`' then `1,2,3,4,` should exactly matches 4 times.

From the result of the compiler I guess it is not like regular expressions but the `$(),*` is more like a join rule as `','.join(...)`?

Comment: Can you link to the section of the book? I think it's incorrect. `$(foo,)*` means the trailing comma is required to match, `$(foo),*` means the trailing comma will not match.

Comment: To optionally accept the trailing comma, you can do something like `$(foo),* $(,)?`

Comment: https://rust-book.cs.brown.edu/ch19-06-macros.html#declarative-macros-with-macro_rules-for-general-metaprogramming  @PitaJ

Comment: So I should view `,*` as whole then?

Comment: That part of the book is misleading. I'm not sure what you mean by "view `,*` as whole". Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: that `,*` acts like a join operator, which explains why there cannot be a trailing comma.

Comment: Yes thinking of it like join is accurate.

Comment: @PitaJ I usually use the `$(,)?` hack as well but I dislike that, when the prior group is `*`, it allows you to have zero repetitions of the group and still have a `,`.